# Will the Gmail Offers Publisher Name override Sender Name?

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

In the specification for "Offer with publisher details," there is the requirement for a Publisher Name. Will that override the actual Sender Name from the email header, or, if not, how does the Publisher Name factor in?

Answer (score 0):

The `publisher.name` property is currently not used, and the sender name is taken from the email headers. Similarly, the `publisher.url` property is not used at this time, while `publisher.url/googlePlus` is used to link the email sender to the Google+ page and extract the logo.